# QR code result (NSString) present in UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Long time ago, I have asked this question, but I didn't make it at that time. Now I have changed some code so it's better for me to open a question again.

I'm going to present a webpage in a `UIWebView` in which the url is taken from QR code reader. So far, I'm able to produce `NSString` url from the reader. However, the webpage did not open in `UIWebView`.

My code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    [self.view addSubview:_webView1];
}

- (void)loadWebView1WithURLString:(NSString *) urlString
{
    urlString = [Collection_01ViewController getResultText];
    NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *webURLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL];
    [_webView1 loadRequest:webURLRequest];
}
```

I have a method,

```
+ (NSString*) getResultText;
```

in another class.

Am I missing anything?

PS: I can provide more code if required.

Comment: Why do you ignore the `urlString` parameter and set it to another value? Are you sure the URL is a valid http URL?

Comment: NSLog your urlString, whats coming in urlString is important. May be it is not appropriate url.

Comment: @rmaddy you mean the problem is caused by incorrect url format?? are these code correct??

Comment: If `urlString` is a valid URL then the code looks like it should work. Again, why do you ignore the `urlString` parameter of your `loadWebView1WithURLString:` method?

Comment: @rmaddy as I'm a beginner, I have followed some tutorial for these codes so i do not know how fix it if I have actually ignored some thing. could you tell me where the urlstring should be placed?